# Create security group tags using Python boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm creating a security group using the following code and would like to create a tag **Name** = SECURITY_GROUP_NAME (using my second argument).

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
region = "us-east-1"

VPC_ID=sys.argv[1]
SECURITY_GROUP_NAME=sys.argv[2]
DESCRIPTION=sys.argv[3]
IP_PROTOCOL_1=sys.argv[4]
FROM_PORT_1=sys.argv[5]
TO_PORT_1=sys.argv[6]
CIDR_IP_1=sys.argv[7]

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2.describe_vpcs()

vpc_id = VPC_ID

try:
    response = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName=SECURITY_GROUP_NAME,Description=DESCRIPTION,VpcId=VPC_ID)
    security_group_id = response['GroupId']
    print('Security Group Created %s in vpc %s.' % (security_group_id, vpc_id))

    data = ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        GroupId=security_group_id,
        IpPermissions=[
            {'IpProtocol': IP_PROTOCOL_1,
             'FromPort': int(FROM_PORT_1),
             'ToPort': int(TO_PORT_1),
             'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': CIDR_IP_1}]}
        ]
    )
    print('Ingress Successfully Set %s' % data)
except ClientError as e:
    print(e)
```

I would like to use security_group.create_tags but not sure how to get this to work and what do I define security_group as?

```
tag = security_group.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'Name','Value': SECURITY_GROUP_NAME},])
```

Comment: Create it like: `ec2.create_tags(Resources=[security_group_id], Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': SECURITY_GROUP_NAME}])`.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004, That worked for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In that example `security_group` is a [security group resource](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#securitygroup). You would create that like so:

```
ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
security_group = ec2_resource.SecurityGroup(security_group_id)
```

Comment: It looks like you need to start with an EC2 resource object, not a client object. You could literally just copy/paste the first two lines of code from the documentation I linked. See my updated answer.